# Best practices about deploying an iOS application to the App Store using Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm currently developing a native (Objective C) iOS application (for iPhone and iPad) that I plan to put on the App Store (iOS 6.1 using Xcode 4.6.1 on Mountain Lion 10.8.3).

This application will need to have some data stored locally on the device in order to make my application still works when offline (no network).  I chose to use Core Data as it is easy to use and you can still do some more complicated stuff with it.

My question... what are the best practices about deploying an application to the App Store using a Core Data database?

1) Deploy my application with an empty Core Data database and have it automatically download the data on first launch or when the user click on some refresh button?

PROS:

- The user can once in a while click some refresh button to have the application data being updated (no need to update the whole application, just update the data).

CONS:

- The application won't be usable until the database has been populated.
- Must maintain and host a web service on a server somewhere to respond to calls from the application (cost for hosting, must develop a brand new web service, another point of failure)

2) Deploy my application with a pre-filled Core Data database and have the user update the application from the App Store when I change the data once in a while?

PROS:

- The application will be working right away after download from the App Store.
- No need to have a server side.

CONS:

- If I want to refresh the data, the user must update the whole application from the App Store.

The easiest for me, the developer, would be #2, as I don't have to deploy a server side application... but can this even be done?  I can easily create a dummy class that would fill the database on my iPhone simulator, but is it possible to bundle this database with my application and deploy it to the App Store?  Is #1 the only way to go (or the best way to go)?  Is there a 3rd option I haven't thought about?

I would be curious to hear about your experiences with this... and don't be afraid to throw in any advices you can think of.  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I've read about core data there should be no problem to ship your app with an existing persistent store, it's just a file. I don't know exactly where the simulator stores it's documents though.

Comment: I would like to know how to ship an app with an existing, pre-filled core data database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what you need/want to do. Both approaches are valid and possible. I have personally implemented both.

Here is what I can tell you:

- **Information will change**: Unless you are writing an app about Math, were most likely things will never change (unless there was an error originally). It can make your app be incorrect/outdated pretty fast. Sending an app update will take some time.
- **Internet might be unreliable**: You can assume users will have a data connection to download the app. However, that does not mean they will have one the first time they open the app. Sometimes they will set it to download and set their device aside. They might open the app later, and there might not be a data connection present.
- **You can do a mix of both**: We developed an app that was meant as a self-guided tour of a place where there is poor cell reception. Visitors were encouraged to use the Information Center WIFI to download the app, but once they stepped out of the door it cell reception was poor/unavailable. We had to include a pre-populated SQL in the bundle. If there is no internet when the app is first opened, then it will load automatically from the bundle, otherwise it downloads it from a simple service (pretty much a dump) where information can be easily updated.

Again, it really depends on what you are trying to do and what your requirements and contraints are. In essence they are both valid and doable approaches. I personally prefer having a way to updating information without having to send an app update that, in my experience, can take weeks before it becomes publicly available.

There are libraries out there that will do most of the web service client implementation for you (JSON and XML parsers). Including them is fairly easy. All you have to do is to display that information through a url.

Back to your "can I include bundle a database" question. Yes, you can. This is how you can import a SQLite file from your bundle:

Do this in your `persistendStoreCoordinator` in your app delegate

```
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath(@"YourSQLFile.sqlite")]) {

        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourSQLFile" ofType:@"sqlite"];

        NSError *error = nil;


        if(defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:[storeURL path] error:&error];
        }

    }
```

Comment: My application data will change, maybe not that often, but it will change for sure.  I would be interested in hearing more about how you were able to "include a pre-populated SQL in the bundle" and about how you "download it from a simple service (pretty much a dump)".  I would appreciate if you could elabore a bit more on those.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not worried about the web service client implementation at all, but more about how you ship an app with an existing, pre-filled core data database and about how you implement a server side service (I'm just a developer at home, I would have to find a place to host this?)

Comment: @Ares, Is SQLite and Core Data the same thing?  I'm using Core Data, will your example still works?

Comment: @Pascal SQLite is the default underlying database for Core Data. Unless you, specifically change it, Core Data will use a SQLite database.

Comment: @Pascal No problem. If you think this answers your question please mark it as "right answer" for future reference.